# Finding the largest subsets of consecutive rows with a maximum gap size (gaps and islands)

Tags: sql

I'm trying to solve a SQL puzzle.  The goal is to find subsets  wherein the acceptible gap size is less than some maximum.  Think of (say) searching for suspicious credit card behaviour by looking for *n* transactions within *m* minutes.

I'm using Postgres 9.6, but a correct solution to the puzzle sticks to ANSI SQL:2008.

**Input**

| t | amt |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 4 | 10 |
| 16 | 40 |
| 20 | 10 |
| 30 | 50 |
| 60 | 5 |
| 61 | 5 |
| 62 | 5 |
| 63 | 5 |
| 72 | 5 |
| 90 | 30 |

```sql
create table d(t int, amt int);

insert into d
values (1, 10),
       (4, 10),
       (16, 40),
       (20, 10),
       (30, 50),
       (60, 5),
       (61, 5),
       (62, 5),
       (63, 5),
       (72, 5),
       (90, 30);
```

**Expected Output**

All subsequences such that the difference of t with the previous row is less than 10.

| start_t | end_t | cnt | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 2 | 20 |
| 16 | 20 | 2 | 50 |
| 30 | 30 | 1 | 50 |
| 60 | 72 | 5 | 25 |
| 90 | 90 | 1 | 30 |

**Notes**

I've tried the "difference of row_number" (Tabibitosan method), but the fact that `t` is not necessarily consecutive foiled my efforts.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You forgot to ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flag the start of group and aggregate groups

```
select min(t) start_t, max(t) end_t, count(*) cnt, sum(amt) total
from (
  select t, amt, sum(flag) over(order by t) grp
     from (
     select t, amt, case when t - lag(t, 1, t-11) over(order by t) >= 10 then 1 end flag
     from d
  ) t
) t
group by grp
```

Comment: Wow, excellent.  I had figured out using flags to mark the start of groups, but missed using sum to turn the flags into group identifiers.  Thank you very much @Serg!

Comment: Should it help anyone else in the future, here's the SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a1d59/2